# How to bind Linq Multiple models data in a View using ViewBag MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, viewbag

I am using `LINQ` to join multiple model classes and pass the `Linq` object to `View` using `ViewBag`.

I am facing problem while repeating data or binding data

Model Properties:

```
public class SalesModel
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public int SSN { get; set; }
    public int LicenseId { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    //Vehicle Sales
    public DateTime? SaleDate { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int SelecteModle { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult CreateVehicleSalesView()
{
    var make = objVehicleContext.VehicleMakes;

    SalesModel objSalesModle = new SalesModel()
    {
        MakesList = new SelectList(make, "MakeId", "Make")
    };

    VehicleDataContext objDataContext = new VehicleDataContext();
    var vehcileSalesDetails = from VS in objDataContext.Vehiclesales
                              join VModel in objDataContext.VehicleModels on VS.ModelId equals VModel.ModelId
                              join Cus in objDataContext.Customers on VS.customerId equals Cus.customerId
                              join VMake in objDataContext.VehicleMakes on VModel.MakeId equals VMake.MakeId
                              select new
                              {
                                  Name = Cus.customerName,
                                  age = Cus.Age,
                                  city = Cus.City,
                                  licenseId = Cus.LicesnseId,
                                  make = VMake.Make,
                                  model = VModel.Model,
                                  year = VModel.Year,
                                  saleDate = VS.SaleDate


                              };
    ViewBag.vehicleSalesDetails = vehcileSalesDetails;                                         

    return View(objSalesModle);
}
```

View:
I have problem while binding data, How to call Linq column names in a view?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>City</td>
        <td>Make</td>
        <td>Model</td>
        <td>Year</td>
        <td>Sale Date</td>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var v in ()ViewBag.vehicleSalesDetails)
    {
        <tr>@v.Name</tr>
        <tr>@v.Age</tr>
        <tr>@v.City</tr>
        <tr>@v.Model</tr>
        <tr>@v.Year</tr>
        <tr>@v.SaleDate</tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: Create a view model with those 8 properties and use `select new MyViewModel { Name = Cus.customerName, ......}` and pass the model to the view (not using `ViewBag`)

Answer (score 0):

Viewbag has a dynamic construction and I don't recommend to return your object in viewbag. Maintanence is diffucult with dynamics.

You can either add other properties to your `SalesModel` or create new model to return view like `VehicleSalesDetailModel`. I recommend to create a new model like:

```
public class SalesModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //Change XXX with Make's type
    public XXX Make {get;set;} 

    public int LicenseId { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    //Vehicle Sales
    public DateTime? SaleDate { get; set; } 

    public int Year{ get; set; }

}
```

And in your action:

```
 public ActionResult CreateVehicleSalesView()
 {
    var make = objVehicleContext.VehicleMakes;

SalesModel objSalesModle = new SalesModel()
{
    MakesList = new SelectList(make, "MakeId", "Make")
};


VehicleDataContext objDataContext = new VehicleDataContext();
VehicleSalesDetailModel vehcileSalesDetails = from VS in objDataContext.Vehiclesales
                          join VModel in objDataContext.VehicleModels on VS.ModelId equals VModel.ModelId
                          join Cus in objDataContext.Customers on VS.customerId equals Cus.customerId
                          join VMake in objDataContext.VehicleMakes on VModel.MakeId equals VMake.MakeId
                          select new VehicleSalesDetailModel
                          {
                              Name = Cus.customerName,
                              Age = Cus.Age,
                              City = Cus.City,
                              LicenseId = Cus.LicesnseId,
                              Make = VMake.Make,
                              Model = VModel.Model,
                              Year = VModel.Year,
                              SaleDate = VS.SaleDate


                          };
return View(vehcileSalesDetails);
}
```

Comment: Okay, What about ->    return View(objSalesModle); I am using this to bind dropdown

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

```
public class VehiclesSaveAndDetails
{
    public SalesModel _salesModle { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable< SalesDetailsTable> _SalesDetailsTable { get; set; }
}

        public ActionResult VehicleSaveAndDetails()
        {
            var make = objVehicleContext.VehicleMakes;

            SalesModel objSalesModle = new SalesModel()
            {
                MakesList = new SelectList(make, "MakeId", "Make")
            };

            VehicleDataContext objDataContext = new VehicleDataContext();

            IEnumerable<SalesDetailsTable> vehcileSalesDetails = from VS in objDataContext.Vehiclesales
                                                          join VModel in objDataContext.VehicleModels on VS.ModelId equals VModel.ModelId
                                                          join Cus in objDataContext.Customers on VS.customerId equals Cus.customerId
                                                          join VMake in objDataContext.VehicleMakes on VModel.MakeId equals VMake.MakeId
                                                                 select new SalesDetailsTable
                                                          {
                                                              CustomerName = Cus.customerName,
                                                              Age = Cus.Age,
                                                              City = Cus.City,
                                                              LicenseId = Cus.LicesnseId,
                                                              MakeName = VMake.Make,
                                                              ModelName = VModel.Model,
                                                              // = VModel.Year,
                                                              SaleDate = VS.SaleDate


                                                          };

            VehiclesSaveAndDetails obj = new VehiclesSaveAndDetails();
            obj._salesModle = objSalesModle;
            obj._SalesDetailsTable = vehcileSalesDetails;

            return View(obj);

        }
```

MyView.

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.VehiclesSaveAndDetails
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "VehicleSaveAndDeatils";
}

<h2>VehicleSaveAndDeatils</h2>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Dropdownlist Selectedchange event
        $('#ddlMake').change(function () {
           // $("#ddlModel").empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/iRateBook/FillModel",
                dataType: "json",
                traditional: true,
                data: { makeId: $(this).val() },
                success: function (data) {
                    //alert("hello"+data.Model[0]);

                    $("#ddlModel").empty();

                    $.each(data, function (i, data) {      // bind the dropdown list using json result
                        $('<option>',
                           {
                               value: data.ModelId,
                               text: data.Model
                           }).html(data.CityName).appendTo("#ddlModel");
                    });


                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve states.' + ex);
                }
            });
            return false;
        })


    });

</script>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreateVehicleSalesView";
}

<h2>CreateVehicleSalesView</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveVehcileSales", "iRateBook"))
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Customer Name: </td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m._salesModle.CustomerName) </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>SSN</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m._salesModle.SSN)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>License Number</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m._salesModle.LicenseId)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Age:</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m._salesModle.Age)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>City :</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m._salesModle.City)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Select Make:</td>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m._salesModle.SelectedMake, Model._salesModle.MakesList, new
                    {
                        @id = "ddlMake"
                    })
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Select Model</td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m._salesModle.SelecteModle, new List<SelectListItem>(), new { @id = "ddlModel" })</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Save" /> </td>

        </tr>
    </table>

    <br />
    <br />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Age</td>
            <td>City</td>
            <td>Make</td>
            <td>Model</td>
            <td>Sale Date</td>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var v in   Model._SalesDetailsTable)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@v.CustomerName</td>
                <td>@v.Age</td>
                <td>@v.City</td>
                <td>@v.MakeName</td>
                <td>@v.ModelName</td>
                <td>@v.SaleDate</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>



}
```